# Opening An sqlite database in android

Tags: android

I have been trying to open my ready made sqlite data base

in my android application my question is:

how do I open an sqlite database with the function:

openOrCreateDatabase();

And where should i put the sqlite file

And if my approach is wrong please enlighten me

Answer (score 1):

Best way to work with SQLLite on Android is having a class which extend SQLiteOpenHelper. Here is good end-end example on how to work with SQLLite on Android. http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html). You can extend it to create your own helper class.